# Vertical line not expanding vertically[android shape]

Tags: android, layout, view, line

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:visible="true"
    android:shape="line">

<stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#008000"
        android:dashWidth="2dp"
        android:dashGap="2dp"/>


</shape>
```

#horizontal_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/horizontal_line"
    >

</rotate>
```

#above is the vertical line xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/dark_red_color">


<View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="310dp"
        android:background="@drawable/vertical_line"
        >

</View>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to use the vertical line in the above layout or view .But the vertical line does not expand fully to its height.

Comment: Have you got the solution for this , because i am facing the same issue .

Comment: I got a fix. Use negative margin in your layout xml
Like this:

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_vertical_line" />

Answer (score 2):

I got a fix. Use negative margin in your layout xml
Like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_vertical_line" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `shape` you can use this

```
<View
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FF0000FF"
android:rotation="90"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Or if you want to use with `Shape` instead of use `line` you can use `rectangle` like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/red"/>
<size android:width="2dp" android:height="290dp" />
</shape>
```

**EDIT**

You have to replace the old shape for this one, and I think it will work :)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
       android:width="1dp"
       android:dashWidth="10px"
       android:dashGap="10px"
       android:rotation="90" 
       />
    </shape>
```

Comment: i wanted the dotted line...to spread vertically.With simple color as background/drawable it can be achieved.But it will not generate dotted line.

Comment: by reducing the rectangle width ... left and right line of rectangle overlap and so perfect vertical dotted line is not achieved.